# why can I not use the dummy parameter in postfix operator++ like someClassObject++5?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I know I can use a dummy int in the postfix operator++ as `someClassObject.operator++(5)`, but why can't use it like `someClassObject++5`? I am asking this because `operator+` can be used like `someClassObject1 + someClassObject2`.

```
{
public:

    test(int x, string y) : x(x), y(y){}
    test() :x(0), y("") {};

    //skiping some code for copy constructor and assignment operator overload

    test operator++(int x)
    {
        test a(*this);
        a.x += x;
        ++(*this);
        return a;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const test& test)
    {
        ost << test.x << " , " << test.y;
        return ost;
    }


    int x;
    string y;
};

int main()
{
    test t1(5, "testing");
    int x = 10;
    cout << t1.operator++(x) << endl;
    //the above line of code works but the line below gives error.
    t1++x;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting both `t1.operator++(5)` and `t1++5` would work in the same way.

Comment: The parameter for the postfix `++` (and `--`) is a hack (or a clever workaround, depending on your perspective) that was introduced only to allow overloading of both the pre- and postfix operators. You're not supposed to use it for anything.

Comment: My guess is that nowadays, if a redesign were possible then it would be distinguished by a tag type argument rather than the non-obvious int overload, e.g. overloading `MyClass& operator++(std::prefix_t)` vs. `MyClass operator++(std::postfix_t)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the *maximal munch* rule, the expression

```
t1++x
```

is *parsed* as

```
t1 ++ x
```

and *grouped* as

```
(t1 ++) x
```

This makes no sense; rather like `t1 x` makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Your answer makes perfect sense. I will research what maximal munch rule is.

Answer (score 0):

> **I know I can use a dummy int in the postfix operator++ as someClassObject.operator++(5), but why can't use it like someClassObject++5?**

Because the Standard Says So™.

Due to how C++ code gets parsed and compiled, postfix `++` and `--` work a bit different.

Let's have a look at the [C++11 standard [draft]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

> #### 13.5.1 Unary operators [over.unary]
>
> [...] See 13.5.7 for an explanation of the postfix unary operators `++` and `--`.

Okay, so `++` and `--` are considered unary operators (i.e. accepts one operand). Something like `1 ++ 2` implies that `++` is a binary operator (i.e. accepts two operands). But there is no binary `++` operator. The postfix `++` operator is to be *overloaded* like one, but it actually isn't resolved as one. Let's flip back a bit through the standard.

> #### 13.3.1.2  Operators in expressions [over.match.oper]
>
> If either operand has a type that is a class or an enumeration, a user-defined operator function might be declared that implements this operator<sup>†</sup> or a user-defined conversion can be necessary to convert the operand to a type that is appropriate for a built-in operator. In this case, **overload resolution is used to determine which operator function or built-in operator is to be invoked to implement the operator**. Therefore, the operator notation is first transformed to the equivalent function-call notation as summarized in Table 11 (where `@` denotes one of the operators covered in the specified subclause).
>
> ```
>  Table 11 — Relationship between operator and function call notation 
> Subclause  | Expression | As member function | As non-member function
>                            [...]
> 13.5.2     | a@b        | (a).operator@(b)   | operator@ (a, b)
>                            [...]
> 13.5.7     | a@         | (a).operator@(0)   | operator@ (a, 0)
> ```

<sup>*(emphasis added)*</sup>
<sup>† *`someClassObject` is a class and a user-defined operator function (`test operator++(int x)`) is declared, so this particular clause applies to your case.*</sup>

Firstly, I included the row with subclause 13.5.2 to clear any doubts. §13.5.2 deals with binary operators. But as we've established, there is no binary `++` operator in C++ and the only postfix `++` operator is an unary. So that row doesn't apply.

The last row is more interesting. According to this, postfix increment will be "transformed" from say, `obj++` to `obj.operator++(0)`. This means an `int` is already passed due to overload resolution.

Just for completeness, here's §13.5.7:

> #### 13.5.7 [over.inc]
>
> The user-defined function called `operator++` implements the prefix and postfix `++` operator. If this function is a member function with no parameters, or a non-member function with one parameter of class or enumeration type, it defines the prefix increment operator `++` for objects of that type. If the function is a member function with one parameter (which shall be of type `int`) or a non-member function with two parameters (the second of which shall be of type `int`), it defines the postfix increment operator `++` for objects of that type. When the postfix increment is called as a result of using the `++` operator, the `int` argument will have value zero.

> **I am asking this because `operator+` can be used like `someClassObject1 + someClassObject2`.**

`+` can be both a unary and binary operator. That's why `+2` and `1 + 2` are both valid expressions. But `++` is an unary operator (even though it's overloaded like a binary one).